# "Temporary failure in name resolution" error on ping ubuntu shell scripting

Tags: bash, sh, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to ping an IP address and store the average round time trip for 5(for example) packets sent to an IP address. The value for amount the packets are stored as a variable and the IP addresses come from a file. This is my code

```
for line in $(ls -1 "$file"); 
do
    avg=$(ping -c $COUNT $line | awk '/avg/ {split($0,arr,"/"); print arr[5]}')
    echo "$avg"
done
```

When I run the ping command in the terminal and add a packet count and IP address, the command works and returns the value, but when I try to run the file, it returns the error message, "ping: file: Temporary failure in name resolution". Any ideas of why this is happening.

- using Ubuntu 18.04 operating system
- using Shell Scripting (.sh file type)

Comment: Suggest running with `set -x` as the 2nd line in script and examining content of `$line` (or just add `echo "line: $line"` before your command substitution). If it works in the terminal, there is no reason ping won't work in a script. ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (there is a reason it is **#1**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over the file's name; there is no IP address corresponding to the server name `file`.

[You should not use a `for` loop in the first place](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and absolutely not [using `ls` for anything in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and of course you will also want to avoid the [useless `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo).

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ping -c "$COUNT" "$line" | awk '/avg/ {split($0,arr,"/"); print arr[5]}'
done<"$file"
```

Going forward, please try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance, and read the error messages you get.